# Is there a way to extract a value from log and use it further to extract another value using bash

Tags: bash, logging, awk, grep

I am trying to read a value from log file and then search another text based on this value .

Below is how my log file looks like. all I have with me is the customerId , the order ID is dynamically generated

I want to capture the orderId first based on customerId and store in a variable.

once successful I want to check the status of this order id which is some 10 lines below

Finally, print it in console or write to a file doesn't matter

```
    2019-05-18 09:46:02.944 [thread-2         ] Orderprocesing:  Sending order info '{
  "customerName" : "jenny",
  "customerId" : "JE19802501",
  "customerphone" : null,
  "orderId" : "8456/72530548",
  "orderInfo" : {
    "Item" : "comic series 2018",
    "count" : "10"

  }
}'
.............................................................
.............................................................
2019-05-18 09:46:02.944 [thread-2         ] Orderprocesing:  Sending order info '{
  "customerName" : "jenny",
  "customerId" : "JE19802501",
  "customerphone" : null,
  "orderId" : "8456/82530548",
  "orderInfo" : {
    "Item" : "comic series 2019",
    "count" : "10"

  }
}'

.............................................................
.............................................................
2019-05-18 09:49:02.944 [thread-2         ] Orderprocesing:  status for 82530548 is success
.............................................................
.............................................................
.............................................................
2019-05-18 09:50:06.872 [thread-2         ] Orderprocesing:  status for 72530548 is success
```

I am new bash, I managed to slice a block of 10 lines that contains the OrderId corresponding to CustomerID but couldn't slice the OrderId and store it in a variable

```
$ cat orderlog_may_18 grep -A 15 "JE19802501"
```

expected results are to print

```
customerId : JE19802501
orderId : 72530548
status for 72530548 is success
customerId : JE19802501
orderId : 82530548
status for 82530548 is success
```

Answer (score 1):

Two lines of bash, using sed.

```
ord=$(sed -n '/JE19802501/,/orderId/{/orderId/{s/[^0-9]//gp}}' orderlog_may18)
sed -n "/status for $ord/s/.*://p" orderlog_may18
```

$ord stores the numerals from the orderId line subsequent to JE198002501
The tail end of the status line is then printed.

You should be able to do the formatting you want in your bash script.

Comment: thanks stevesliva, worked fine as I expected. I took some time to understand the regex concepts :)

Comment: No problem.   The explanation was terse because I often get followups along the lines of "that's not what I want at all" ... so I try not to go too far down the wrong path w/o feedback.

Comment: Some of the order id's has leading numbers like this "orderId" : "8456/72530548" is there a way to cut this numbers that always has slash at the end?

Comment: Insert a replacement using `s%%%` so you don't have to escape the slash: `/orderId/{s%.*/%%;s/[^0-9]//gp}`.  That is, once you're on the orderId line you want to strip down to a number, remove everything up to the last slash, and then remove everything except numerals, and then print.

Comment: thanks, stevesliva worked fine I was able to split it, I bumped into real problem a customer has more than one order, I get an error "sed: -e expression #1, char 20: unterminated address regex" when I try. I updated the log text in question

Comment: here is my code `ord=$(sed -n '/JE19802501/,/orderId/{/orderId/{s%.*/%%;s/[^0-9]//gp}}' orderlog_may18)
echo "status for "$ord
sed -n "/status for $ord/s/.*://p" orderlog_may18`

Comment: Is there still an issue?

Comment: Yes @stevesliva please see my earlier comment. I have also updated my question the part with texts from log

Answer (score 1):

```
$ awk -v trgt='JE19802501' '
    { gsub(/[",]/," "); $1=$1 }
    $1 == "customerId"                  { cust=$NF; print }
    ($1 == "orderId") && (cust == trgt) { ordr=$NF; print }
    $0 ~ ("status for " ordr " is")     { sub(/.*: /,""); print }
' file
customerId : JE19802501
orderId : 72530548
status for 72530548 is success
```